# Test for a column within a Select statement

Tags: sql-server-2016

Is it possible to test for a column before selecting it within a select statement?

This may be rough for me to explain, I have actually had to teach myself dynamic SQL over the past 4 months. I am using a dynamically generated parameter (`@TableName`) to store individual tables within a loop (apologize for the vagueness, but the details aren't relevant).

I then want to be able to be able to conditionally select a column from the table (I will not know if each table has certain columns). I have figured out how to check for a column outside of a select statement...

```
SET @SQLQuery2 = 'Select @OPFolderIDColumnCheck = Column_Name From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS Where Table_Name = @TABLENAME And Column_Name = ''OP__FolderID'''
SET @ParameterDefinition2 = N'@TABLENAME VARCHAR(100), @OPFolderIDColumnCheck VARCHAR(100) OUTPUT'
EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @SQLQuery2, @ParameterDefinition2, @TABLENAME, @OPFolderIDColumnCheck OUTPUT      

IF @OPFolderIDColumnCheck IS NULL
BEGIN           
    SET @OP__FOLDERID = NULL
END
ELSE
    IF @OPFolderIDColumnCheck IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        ...etc
```

but id like to be able to do it inside of a select statement. Is there a way to check and see if `OP__FOLDERID` exists in the table?

Id like to be able to do something like this:

```
SELECT IF 'OP__FOLDERID' EXISTS IN [TABLE] THEN 'OP__FOLDERID' FROM [TABLE]
```

Thank you for any help or direction you can offer.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/66755/3690

Comment: @MartinSmith Thanks for the link! That was super helpful.

Comment: @Marc_S Thanks for the edits. I am still learning how to post on here and am SUPER new to coding. I found myself in a job where Ive had to teach myself. Appreciate the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there isn't any direct way to do this within a SELECT statement at all. You *can* determine if a column exists in a table, however, and construct your dynamic SQL accordingly. To do this, use something like this:

```
IF COL_LENGTH('schemaName.tableName', 'columnName') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    -- Column Exists
END
```

You could then set a variable as a flag, and the code to construct the dynamic SQL would construct the expression with/without the column, as desired. Another approach would be to use a string value, and set it to the column name if it is present (perhaps with a prefix or suffix comma, as appropriate to the expression). This would allow you to save writing conditionals in the expression building, and would be particularly helpful where you have more than one or two of these maybe-columns in a dynamic expression.

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you. This helps a lot in some other things as well.